# Prove that two graphs are the same given that the breadth first and depth first search trees are the same

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, trees

> We have a connected graph $G = (V, E)$, and a specific vertex $u \in V$. Suppose we compute a depth-first search tree rooted at $u$ and obtain a tree $T$ that includes all nodes of $G$. Suppose we then compute a breadth-first search tree rooted at $u$, and obtain the same tree $T$. Prove that $G=T$.

I approached this problem by trying to show that all nodes and edges in $G$ are in $T$ and all nodes and edges in $T$ are in $G$.

Since $T$ is a subtree of $G$, all nodes and edges of $T$ are in $G$.

It is also given that all nodes in $G$ are in $T$.

Therefore, we just need to prove that all edges in $G$ are in $T$.

I tried to prove this by contradiction.

Assume there exists edge $e$ where $e$ is in $G$ but not in $T$

Since $e$ does not appear in the breadth first search, it means that it connects two vertices that have the same minimum distance from root vertex $u$. (Since the edge connects two vertices in the same layer of the breadth first search)

This is where I got to in my proof. Could I get some hints on how to complete it?

Comment: Your last assertion is wrong. Take a square, the missing edge in the BFS tree will link two vertices with different depths.
We can interpret the question in two non-equivalents ways: $T$ is the same labelled tree (with the same labels than in $G$), or the two trees are isomorphic (disregarding the labels). The second interpretation is harder to handle.
For the first interpretation, show that the extremities of $e$ are on a common path on the DFS tree, but not on the BFS one.
For the second interpretation, you can show that the sum of depths in the two trees differ.